# How to run construct function with static Method

Tags: php, oop

When I run my script I saw blank page means didn't get any value. Please check my code where I am wrong and also why this happening.

```
<?php

    class house{
        public static $size;
        public static $width;

        public static function getsize() {
            return  self::$size;
        }

        public static function getwidth() {
            return  self::$width;
        }

        public function __construct($widthh,$sizee) {
            self::$size=$sizee;
            self::$width=$widthh;   
        }
    }
    $myhousesize = house::getsize('4',' 10');
    echo $myhousesize;
?>
```

So, this is my code I used construct function used to check but nothing work. How is this possible?

Comment: Please indent your code

Comment: Means where i am wrong?? will you please tell me answer ??

Answer (score 0):

A constructor runs only when the object is instanciated.
First instantiate your object, then the `__construct` method will run, then `$size` and `$width` will be set.

```
$h = new house(4,10);
$myHouseSize = house::getsize();
echo $myHouseSize; // will echo 10
```

If you don't want to instantiate an object first, then don't do a constructor but a common method that will set your var and check in `getsize()` if `$size` and `$width` are set or not, then set them if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably misunderstood some basic aspect of OOP in PHP.

First of all, the constructor of a class is invoked when you instantiate a new object, like this:

```
$house = new house('4','10').
```

What you are doing is calling a static method of your class with two arguments that are not used.

Secondly, it's not really clear why you would want to use static fields and methods, as these belong to the class itself and not individual instances.

What you probably wanted to do was something like this:

```
class House{
   private $width;
   private $size;

   public function __construct($width,$size){
     $this->width = $width;
     $this->height = $size;
   }

   public function getSize(){
     return $this->size;
   }

   public function getWidth(){
     return $this->width;
   }
}

$house = new House(4,10);
echo $house->getSize();
```